# Tensorflow weird GPU memory usage universal-sentence-encoder

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu, embedding, nvidia-titan

Hi I am new to TensorFlow, GPU,Models everything :)

I am using the below code to generate text embeddings

```
texts = [ "This is the first sentence.","Another sentence for embedding.","Embeddings are useful for NLP."]
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

# Path to the saved USE model directory
use_model_path = "universal-sentence-encoder"
# Configure GPU memory growth
gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
if gpus:
    for gpu in gpus:
        tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(gpu, True)
        
use_model = tf.saved_model.load(use_model_path)

embeddings_list = []
embeddings = use_model(texts)
embeddings_list = embeddings.numpy().tolist()
#clear session
tf.keras.backend.clear_session()


print(embeddings_list)
```

If I execute this in a for loop with a list of 512kb texts, GPU memory increases exponentially.
Even after adding `tf.keras.backend.clear_session()` in every iteration, I see the same behavior.

how can I optimize this?

Comment: It seems like you are facing memory issues when processing a large number of texts in a loop.
Instead of processing texts one by one, you can process them in batches. This can help reduce the memory footprint.
batch_size = 10
embeddings_list = []
for i in range(0, len(texts), batch_size):
    batch_texts = texts[i:i + batch_size]
    embeddings = use_model(batch_texts)
    embeddings_list.extend(embeddings.numpy().tolist())

tf.keras.backend.clear_session()
Load the model once outside the loop and reuse the same instance for all iterations. This avoids unnecessary overhead.